# Does RAID 0 increase the latency of the volume on HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, raid, raid-0

I will add a new HDD to my computer (identical to the old HDD).

I'm wondering if it's a good idea to do a raid 0 vs using the two drive separately.

How much it impact the **latency** and the performance.

Specially for small random read and write.

Answer (score 1):

RAID0 should either do nothing or decrease the impact of latency and increase performance depending on the configuration and load.  I would expect it would have a positive effect for small random read and write.

The disadvantage of RAID0 is that if you have a drive failure, all your information is likely to go, whereas if you use the 2 drives independently you will still have the data from the unaffected drive.

Comment: I do regular backup so I'm more interesting about not having to worry where i should put my data and get better performance. Is there some case when raid-0 is slower?

Comment: Not really.   Worst case would be no better then single disk performance depending on where the data is.